# Subset data table with same value appears more than twice

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, subset

I created a data table `df`

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), starts = c(0,0,6,0,9,0), ends = c(0,6,10,9,20,7))

   #id starts ends
#1:  1      0    0
#2:  1      0    6
#3:  1      6   10
#4:  2      0    9
#5:  2      9   20
#6:  3      0    7
```

I only want to remain the rows with same `id` shows more than twice. In this case, `id == 3` will be omitted.

Expected outcome:

```
#   id starts ends
#1:  1      0    0
#2:  1      0    6
#3:  1      6   10
#4:  2      0    9
#5:  2      9   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', either use an `if` condition  to check the number of rows greater than 1, then get the Subset of data.table

```
df[, if(.N > 1) .SD, id]
```

Or we can directly subset from the logical index

```
df[, .SD[.N >1], id]
```

Or use the row index which would be fast

```
df[df[, .I[.N >1], id]$V1]
```

Or another option is `duplicated` which also works in this example

```
df[duplicated(id)|duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE)]
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I have two criterias. Like same `id` more than 2 or `ends == 20.

Comment: @HongruLiu  In that case, `.N>1 & .N<21`

Comment: `ends` here is another column, not `id`.

Comment: @HongruLiu  It is not clear about the condition.  Did you meant that any of the rows of 'ends' contain 20 for 'id' more than 2?

Comment: @HongruLiu  If the condition is one of the rows of ends is 20 for a particular id that have more than 1 row, then `.N > 1 & any(ends==20)`

Comment: Yes. if `ends == 20` and we do not need to consider the whether `id` appears more than twice. like the `id == 3` in my question. it only has one row but `ends == 20` so we keep it.

Comment: @HongruLiu  You meant for `id==2` right?.  Then ` df[, .SD[.N >1 & any(ends==20)], id]`, only we get id 2 rows

Comment: `#6:  3      0    7` The `df` I created `id == 3` only have one row. I saw your comment. its `.N > 1 & any(ends==20)` or `.N > 1 | any(ends==20)`?

Comment: @HongruLiu  Based on the example showed, what is the expected output